# Tagging latest release?

Tags: git

We have a git repo used for development. From time to time we make releases, marked with tags. There's also an automated build system that we want to build the latest tagged release. Meanwhile commits are pushed as usual.

How do we mark the latest release so that the automated build can pick it up?

It is important that the automated system always picks the version from the same URL. Cannot use a script with `describe` or any other fetch-time method to resolve the latest tag.

The first idea is to use a specific lightweight tag like LAST_RELEASE and move it (delete and recreate?) every time a release is tagged. Another idea is to maintain a separate branch and keep its head in sync with the last release tag. Yet another idea is to use a branch, but instead of keeping it in sync using merges/rebases, just delete and recreate it for each release.

I don't particularly like either of these methods. Is there any established sane way to accomplish this?

Comment: Why do you need to pick the version from the same URL? Also, can't you write a small web application responding on the same URL, but using `describe` under the hood?

Comment: @choroba Because I'm not responsible for the entire company infrastructure. Build people have their build server that runs in a certain way. I can fill in a repo URL to fetch and that's it. I cannot make them write custom build scripts for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way is to use a branch.  You should find that, if done properly, a `stable` branch should always move forwards without any rebasing / force pushing.  Whenever you do a new release, you can checkout your `stable` branch and merge in your `develop` branch.  And whenever you need to hotfix changes into new releases, you can add commits / merge branches into the `stable` branch, and then checkout your `develop` branch and merge in `stable`.

Have a look [here](http://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/) for a commonly used branching model based around this idea.  You should find that the `master` branch in this model is exactly what you need to keep track of the most recent release.

If you are unable to switch to a branching model like this, it would still be better to use branches.  When you want to mark a new release, you checkout your repository to the desired release commit, and run `git push -f origin release`, which has the same effect as deleting and recreating the branch.

Tags are meant to always mark the same commit once they are created.  Branches are meant to move forwards.

Comment: Thank you, this seems reasonable. I probably cannot use master as the stable branch, it doesn't seem to play well with gerrit (or I need to learn more of gerrit). The second option seems simple and straightforward though.

Comment: @n.m. You can use any branch names you want to represent the different branches.

Comment: The problem is in merging, our gerrit setup doesn't like merging, only rebasing. I think this can be problematic when you have to merge in both directions.